# MVC pass value from View (Jquery script) to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to pass a value from the view to the controller the value is retrieve via jquery when I use the code below it does not work the value is null in the controller.

```
  //Hardcoded to test   
  var groupId = 1;
    $('#timeList').load('/Time/Index/' + groupId);

    public ActionResult Index(int? groupId)
    {
        AddProjectToViewData(-1);
        return View(_service.ListTimes());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that you are using default routes in global.asax.cs you can retrieve this value in id

```
public ActionResult index(int? id)
{
     AddProjectToViewData(-1);
     return View(_service.ListTimes());

}
```

if you do wish to receive it in groupid you have to change jquery code a little
  //Hardcoded to test

```
var groupId = 1;
    $('#timeList').load('/Time/Index?groupid=' + groupId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var groupId = 1;
$('#timeList').load('/Time/Index', {groupId: groupId}); //Send named parameter

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int? groupId)
{
    AddProjectToViewData(-1);
    return View(_service.ListTimes());
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You want to do either a post or a get, and I think you may want to pass back a string or json. For ease, I'll show you a get with json:

///your javascript

```
var groupId =1;

$.get('Time/Index/' + groupId, function(data) {
  $('#timeList').val(data);
   ///might need to do a for each since you are returning a list or whatever
});
```

///your controller logic

```
[HttpGet]
public string Index(int? groupId)
    {
        AddProjectToViewData(-1);
        //might want to pass back json here
        return WhateverYourDataIs.ToString();
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: how does it relate to the question? i wouldn't give it -1 though!

Comment: His question specifically states "pass a value from the view to the controller" - that's how it relates.